# Странный баг/лаг в VS C# при загрузке xml-документа

Tags: c#, xml, svg

Ситуация: загружаю два svg-документа, один из моего редактора, второй из стороннего. первый грузится как надо, информация с него считывается, но на загрузке второго брейкпоинт встает на методе xml.Load(ofd.FileName) и дальше не двигается. Такой баг происходит при чтении файлов из стороннего граф. редактора, хотя, файлы моего редактора от тех не отличаются по структуре. Код в аттаче.

```
if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    this.Clear();
    XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
    xml.Load(ofd.FileName); // Повисаем здесь
    ...
}
else
return;
```

Comment: @tym32167 Вам не нужно знать, что идет после строки "xml.Load(ofd.FileName);", т.к. брейкпоинт дальше нее не идет. а так, файл другого редактора нормально читается и не заблочен, конечно

Comment: @VanyaBelyaev https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/cc667410.aspx После этого в стеке вместо "External code" будет стек внутри компонентов .NET Framework. Пример (у тебя вместо Thread.Sleep будет XmlDocument.Load): https://i.imgur.com/RDA36Of.png

Comment: @tym32167 "C:\\Users\\Vanya\\Desktop\\555.svg"

чтоб Вы понимали, открывая документ типа svg, сгенерированный своим редактором, все работает. и код там корректный, т.к. файл из моего редактора читается другими редакторами

Comment: ну если у вас путь правильный, файл не занят другими процессами и доступен для чтения, то осталось только на контент файла поглядеть.

Comment: @tym32167 как выяснилось, вылетает System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException. но как??

Comment: Это вам лучше знать. Смотрите права доступа, проверяйте, есть ли такая папка. Проверяйте, есть ли такой файл перед его загрузкой

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70115/discussion-on-question-by-vanya-belyaev-----vs-c---xm).